# How does Python Interpreter parse statements including the ternary conditional operator?

Tags: python, syntax, interpreter, ternary-operator

For example,
suppose Func1 takes 10 unit time to return a value while Func2 takes 5 unit time to return a value. Which of the following statements takes fewer time than the other does or they take the same amount of time?

Statement1:

```
result = Func1() if (True) else Func2()
```

Statement2:

```
result = Func2() if not (True) else Func1()
```

Comment: Assuming `(Boolean expression)` is the same in both cases, they will take the same amount of time.

Comment: There will be only a minimal difference for the additional `not`.

Answer (score 1):

In the ternary conditional operator, the first of all to be executed is condition evaluation. From your examples, there are no significance difference between evaluting a condition and evaluating the same condition and then negate it.

That said, in both cases, assuming the condition to be `True`, the `Func1()` will be executed, so the both statements would take the same amount of time.

***Edit:***

## Proof

Here's a proof about what I said:

```
from time import sleep

def sleep5():
    print("Sleeping for 5 secs")
    sleep(5)

def sleep1():
    print("Sleeping for 1 sec")
    sleep(1)

def true_condition():
    print("Evaluating condition")
    return True

sleep1() if true_condition() else sleep5() 
'''prints:
Evaluating condition
Sleeping for 1 sec
then waits for 1 second'''

sleep5() if not true_condition() else sleep1() 
'''prints:
Evaluating condition
Sleeping for 1 sec
then waits for 1 second'''

sleep1() if not true_condition() else sleep5() 
'''prints:
Evaluating condition
Sleeping for 5 secs
then waits for 5 seconds'''
```

The first 2 ternary conditionals are equivalent to yours conditionals. The last one illustrates when the other function is called

Comment: "In the ternary conditional operator, the first of all to be executed is condition evaluation.", this is the basis of this question. I'm not sure whether Python performs in this way. I cant find the syntax related to it.

Comment: @LeeChing-Chan I added some code to proof what said. I thought about this for a while and I **think** that this example covers all cases. But if I missed something, let me know.